# Delegate method naming convention if class name is long?

Tags: objective-c, methods, delegates, naming-conventions

I am having a problem with method naming. I want to follow the method naming format as seen in `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

but my class name is much longer than 'UITableView' -- it's `XYPagedContentScrollView` where `XY` is the class prefix for the project. I have a delegate protocol:

```
@protocol XYPagedContentScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (CGFloat)defaultPageHeightForPagedContentScrollView:(XYPagedContentScrollView *)pagedContentScrollView;
@end
```

and this method name looks ridiculously long. I know it is not a strict rule, but I just wonder is there any way to deal with the long name and still conform to Apple's naming convention? Something like:

```
@protocol XYPagedContentScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (CGFloat)defaultPageHeightForPagedContentScrollView:(XYPagedContentScrollView *)pagedContentSV;
@end
```

or even:

```
@protocol XYPagedContentScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (CGFloat)defaultPageHeightForPCScrollView:(XYPagedContentScrollView *)pagedContentSV;
@end
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of a method is not limited by the language in any way, so feel free to make it as long as you want.

It may look bad at first, but the more verbose it is, the less chance you have of conflicts later down the line.

My rule is, if it looks like it could conflict with another method (especially if it's a delegate method), it needs a longer name.

Now, with that said, don't make names ridiculously long,so that they are 100s of characters in length, like this:

```
-(void) fooBarViewController:(FooBarViewController *) controller didTapRightMarginAtPoint:(CGPoint point) ofPage:(NSUInteger) page lengthHeld:(NSTimeInterval) tapLength fingers:(NSUInteger) fingerCount;
```

Instead, consider wrapping it in a  dictionary of the event details:

```
-(void fooBarViewController:(FooBarViewController *) controller didTapMargin:(NSDictionary *) eventDetails; 

/* eventDetails should contain the following information:
    which margin?
    touch location
    page index
    touch length
    finger count
 */
```

This simplifies the method signature, and allows the receiver to only pull out the variables they need.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I would still lean to ridiculously long methods with lots of [optional] arguments for most cases.  You have to test for the items in the dictionary anyway, so testing for the arguments presence is no big deal.   Combined with always having the full prototype with all options *and* Xcode automatic completion, it leads to more fluid code authoring and more signal when reading the code 8 months from now.

Comment: This seems reasonable, but why not use an event *class* for this, rather than a dictionary?

Comment: @JesseRusak either way works, it's just a matter of programming style.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go with the long form: that's what autocomplete is for. That being said, if you do want to shorten it, I would drop adjectives. Something like:

```
@protocol XYPagedContentScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (CGFloat)defaultPageHeightForScrollView:(XYPagedContentScrollView *)pagedContentSV;
@end
```

I wouldn't worry about name conflicts with delegate methods because if an object is ever the delegate of two different object with the same delegate methods, then it will use the passed (i.e. calling) object to distinguish them. (For example, If you're the delegate of two scroll views, you just test the passed view to find which scroll view it's talking about.)

Comment: Drop adjectives, what if I have a custom table view like XYTableView and I need to have a delegate method like numberOfSectionsInTableView:(XYTableView *)tableView?

Comment: That's fine. It won't cause any problems to have a method with the same name as a standard method, because if an object is the delegate of your view and a UITableView, it can use the passed view to determine which one is calling it.

Comment: Yes, but what if you have methodA:(UIView *)view and methodA:(NSPredicate)pred and you pass id someObj to methodA? How does it distinguish?

Comment: Well, you'll have a single implementation of `methodA:` in your class, and in your method you'll probably say something like `if (sender == self.someView) { ... } else if (sender == self.somePredicate) { ... }` just like you would if you were the delegate of two scroll views, say, where you'd implement a `scrollViewDidScroll:` method with `if (sender == self.scrollView1) { ... } else if (sender == self.scrollView2) { ... }`.